# Image is not fitting in image view using Auto layout

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, constants, xib

I have an imageview whose constraints set in XIB, and image for imageview will be a screenshot of the simulator. this is how my xib looks. after creating object for my custom view i am assigning screenshot image to an image view.the problem i am facing is the image is not fitting properly into image view.[image]

Comment: i am setting imagview content mode as aUIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit

Comment: Can you please post a screenshot of it not fitting properly into the image view. Thanks